# Error when creating bitmap text in pixi.js using typescript

Tags: typescript, bitmap, pixi.js

I use typescript and pixijs to code my app. When I create a bitmaptext and set anchor for it, but the typescript shows an error:

> Property 'set' does not exist on type 'number | Point'.
>   Property 'set' does not exist on type 'number'.".

```
var txt = new PIXI.extras.BitmapText("0sfsfds", { font: "15px RockerSmall", align: "center" });
txt.anchor.set(0.5);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky: the `anchor` property is [implemented](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/7210b43d7a66ac114ac7efcea257a29547211168/src/extras/BitmapText.js#L379) so that either a number or a `Point` can be assigned to it, but when read, it always returns a `Point`.  TypeScript can't represent a property with different "get" and "set" types, so the type declaration authors chose to use the "set" type, `number | Point`.  That leaves you the following options: either cast the property to a `Point`:

```
(<PIXI.Point>txt.anchor).set(0.5);
```

or assign a `Point` of your own to the property:

```
txt.anchor = new PIXI.Point(0.5);
```